# Wrapping a link tag around PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

I have the following PHP and need to make what's outputted (subheader, not thumbnail) hyperlinked to the parent directory

```
<?php 
        //$featured_img=get_template_directory_uri().'/img/default.png';
        $featured_img='';
        if(get_the_post_thumbnail_url()) {
            $featured_img=' style="background-image:url('.get_the_post_thumbnail_url().')"';
        }


        $subheader= '<p class="entry-subheader">&nbsp;</p>'; 
        if(get_field('subheader') ) {
            $subheader= '<p class="entry-subheader">'.get_field('subheader').'</p>'; 
        }

    ?>
```

I have no experience in PHP - only self taught in HTML and CSS so struggling as to where to put in the  link.

Comment: Do you literally just mean something like: `$subheader= '<p class="entry-subheader"><a href="../">'.get_field('subheader').'</a></p>'; ` ?

Comment: Exactly that - thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$subheader= '<p class="entry-subheader"><a href="../">'.get_field('subheader').'</a></p>';
```

Cd001's answer worked for me